# Python3 - create global variable(list) from function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, global-variables

I have this code(example):

```
count = 3

def test(count):
    a = 1
    while a <= count:
        global list + str(a)
        list + str(a) = []
        print(a)
        a += 1

test(count)

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
```

How can I create dynamically global variable(list) in function?
I need to make my code working, need access to variables(lists): "list1", "list2" and "list3" from function outside.

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you put `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` in an actual list?  Or better yet, a `dict`?

Comment: You really don't want to do this. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) takes care of your variable variables, and then just return the dictionary.

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Comment: @MorganThrapp So, I can use 1 global dictionary and write some data on it, using dynamic keys?

Comment: Yup, I did already. The link I gave you shows how to make a dictionary, as for returning, you need to read a tutorial. That's Python 101.

Comment: No. No no no. You don't need global variables at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for all.
I used this code:

```
count = 3
urls = {}

def test(count):
    a = 1
    while a <= count:
        urls[a] = 'test'
        a += 1

test(count)
print(urls)
```